# How best to map a network drive from within SSIS

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssis

I've inherited an SSIS package which loads CSV files into a SQL database.

The first thing the package does is call a .BAT file which maps a network drive. The .BAT file contains the username and password used to map the drive in plain text, so urgently needs to be replaced.

I've written a solution which uses New-PSDrive in a Powershell script and creates a credentials XML file with the password encrypted. If I execute the ps1 script it works Ok.

If I call the ps1 script from within SSIS and run it through VS then it also works fine.

When I call the SSIS package that calls the script task through a SQL Agent job (executed as the SQL Server Agent user account) the drive mapping doesn't seem to work, and the package complains it cannot access the file from the file share.

I presume this is no working because the SQL Server Agent user account can't run Powershell queries? The package only errors because it cannot access the share, not during the execution of the Powershell script.

So, two questions:
Is there an obvious issue with the SQL Agent deployment idea
or
Is there a different way of mapping a network drive from within SSIS without storing the password in plain text anywhere?

Comment: Why do you need to create the network drive during the execution of the package?  Why not have it already created and always existing or just work with local paths?

Comment: I just need to make sure the drive is re-connected every time the box is rebooted and the existing package re-maps the drive every time it executes, so I've copied. I still need to map the drive without storing the password in plain text anywhere even if I remove it from SSIS

Comment: If this is a remote drive that you're accessing the files from, I would use the UNC path instead `\\myserver\files` --is that possible?  Sounds like the current strategy is volatile

Comment: It is a remote drive yes, but as it contains gdpr sensitive information it is tightly controlled using a username and password. If I had a way of mapping the drive (using the credentials) every time the box rebooted then I wouldn't really need to re-map every time we processed CSV files, but the old package I inherited did so I just wanted to replace the storage of the password in plain text problem.

Comment: You can add a windows task that runs the script on start up.  I would try anything to avoid having that task in the package.  Also, there are some possibilities with the answer I suggested, i.e. have a dedicated package that moves the files under a proxy and then everything else runs as normal.

Answer (score 1):

This is the pattern I suggest using for accessing files on a remote server:

- Access the files via unc path: `\\MyServer\Files`
- This means that the package needs to run under a context that has access to the path.  There are a couple of options:

1. Run the package under a proxy, i.e. the account credentials that were stored in the bat file.  This means that you have to also grant access to the account on the sql instance as well
2. Use a group managed service account (gMSA).  In this case, the sql agent service account is replaced with the gMSA and the job runs under sql agent.  The gMSA needs to be granted access to the remote share as well as the sql instance.  This is a much more secure way of addressing the whole process because there is no password to manage (AD takes care of that) and the account cannot be used to log in anywhere.  But there is set up work to do to get it created so it's not the fastest option.